# How to get all SNMP items using zabbix?

Tags: centos, monitoring, snmp, zabbix

## Scenario:

**OS:** CentOS 7.2
**Zabbix version:** 3.0
*Trying to monitor some switches using SNMP protocol*

---

I'm able to monitor them without any problem, all items are working and everything is fine but adding every item is a pain in the ass and I'm not into wasting hours right now so I started googling a bit and found [Zabbix Extras](http://spinola.net.br/blog/2014/09/20/zabbix-extras-2-1-versao-micrastur-mintoni/), which seems to fix my problem, but not yet, as the last version is for Zabbix 2.4. Anyways, I tried to install it but, as expected, no success at all. I've been trying to find an alternative and got anything so far so this is basically my last chance...

*hope someone can help or I'm gonna kill myself before adding +500 items/switch lol*

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to add items for all interfaces or disks manually - just use the default templates "Template SNMP Interfaces" and "Template SNMP Disks".

That should cover the absolute majority of items/OIDs and the remainder should be a few that one could add manually (in a template, preferably) - or you could see whether there's an existing template for your device already.

Note that you should never monitor *everything* available over SNMP - there are way, way too many things and you will overload the target device, fill up the Zabbix database and in general gather useless data.

Answer (score 0):

**mib2zabbix**

Perl script will generate a Zabbix v3 Template in XML format from an OID tree in an SNMP MIB file.

Read more here:
https://github.com/cavaliercoder/mib2zabbix